# pandas to JavaScript with bootstable

Tags: javascript, jquery, pandas, flask, bootstrap-4

this might be a noob question because i'm a new dev

i've been researching for best ways to render all pandas result on HTML and manipulate it with **javascript** (not **Jquery**)

i've checked many opensource including (**handsontable**) and (**tabulator**) but they weren't free for commercial use or had many restrictions with it & requires many modifications for every table/file.

i came across (**bootstable**) which was perfect as it transformed my `pandasDf.to_html` to an editable table right away but sadly it uses jquery which is a bit heavy library that i'm trying not to use as i don't think Javascript 6 is hard and fairly easy to use so there's no point to learn **jquery**

the problem is 
**bootstable** is not really backed by many so there's not that many resources about it to master it

so i'm looking for any alternative that can do the same - i couldn't find resources for **editablegrid** either but i have my eye's sit on it as well

or if it's possible to use bootstable with "javascript" instead of "jquery" , is it possible ( i know the it is jquery based ) ?

for example how to transfer this code into JS

```
$('#makeEditable').SetEditable({ $addButton: $('#but_add')});
```

also it uses bootstrap-CNB linked , how safe is it to use a linked library in my code ? also it's a bit slower

If not can you suggest a different table library for me as a new dev?

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator is licensed under MIT so it is completely free for commercial use.

If you have an example of the format of the data you wish to load into the table i can easily show you how to do it. if it is an HTML table then it is as simple as defining the tabulator on the table element:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {});
```

See the [HTML table data loading example](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/data#table) for more information

Comment: I gave it a try the table is so messed up with tabulator , all index (1-38) have turned into columns and many columns data are messed up , they are not in the right column , i can't see any tutorial online or documentations about how to use it properly , or maybe how to install it right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470273/flask-pandas-to-tabulator-tables-are-all-messed-up

Comment: I have left a comment on your new post for you