# flask pandas to tabulator tables are all messed up

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, flask, tabulator

I'm a new Dev , trying to pass Pandas DataFrame to Tabulator , it works but the table is so messed up

original file :
[original file in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U3cV.png)

without tabulator :
[to_html() render result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLWok.png)

it renders fine as html but once i attach Tabulator to it everything is messed up .

after tabulator:
[after attaching tabulator to it using ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IogA.png)

the way i install it was copying and pasting  all files in Dist to my app folder JS files in the JS folder and all CSS files in CSS folder

in HTML head :

```
<link href="{{ url_for ('static', filename='css/tabulator.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"></link>


<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for ('static', filename='tabulator.min.js') }}"></script>
```

HTML Body :

```
var table = new Tabulator("#tableId", {});
```

PYTHON :

```
df = pd.read_excel(destination)

return render_template('fileviewer.html',x=df.to_html(table_id='tableId'))
```

Comment: can you post a sample of you html code (including table headers) and i can point you in the right direction

Comment: that's how it's rendered from the back end  >> https://pastebin.com/BkUVMJAr

Comment: the issue is that it is using th elements for the table cells instead of td elements. th elements should only be used in the thead not the tbody

Comment: this how Panda render's it  , i can render it in json as well , could it work with json ?

Comment: i would check with panda as that isnt valid HTML unfortunately. Yes Tabulator certainly can work with JSON, no problem there! have a look at http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/data#array the function will take either an array of data or JSON encoded array

Comment: thanks but it didnt work with Json either , all i got rendered is the fist raw but without any of the data that goes along with it  , 
https://pastebin.com/n3ZdaKQg , similar to the result i got when i pointed tabulator to the div html code has it instead of the id on the table itself

Comment: you shouldnt be putting the json data in the HTML it should be fed in the JavaScript as per the documentation.  Looking at the data it is being structured in a very odd way, most people would structure it as an array of rows, with each object  being a row and having key value pairs for each column (which is also what Tabulator expects). you seem to be storing it with an object for each column, and then in that an object with a property for each row. that seems a very complicated storage method for some simple data. to get that into Tabulator, or any table library it will need to be reformatted

Comment: i've tried many formats , none of them worked including the array format for ever row in a list https://pastebin.com/rDJerjmm

Comment: basically i'm rendering it from pandas's back end and i only have those options of formatting - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: looking at the documentation, the "records" format is the one you want

Comment: none of the table were rendered except the head titles , all the data beneath it never rendered https://pastebin.com/42gm2mBP

Comment: That is because you are dumping the JSON into your table element, as i mentioned before you need to pass it in the Javascript as per the example on http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/data#array NOT as text in the DIV. You will also need to define the columns in the table constructor now that you are no longer using an HTML table

Comment: well i did it just like the example , still not working but i got the headers to render with 1 row underneath it .... unfortunately it's an empty row :S , i don't understand why is this keeps happening >>>> https://pastebin.com/atJFX6zi

Comment: looking at the data you are passing to the tabledata variable you have nested an array in another array var tableData = [[...]] it should only be one array var tableData = [...], so you can either fix that and not nest the arrays, or if that isnt possible pass the first element of that array into the Tabulator constructor instead of the whole array data:tableData[0]

Comment: i managed to remove the nested list and the results was headers and 47 empty rows ,  the file has 39 rows full of data https://pastebin.com/rh8EkyKL , i dont see anything wrong this time

Comment: the field names in your column definitions are lowercase but the properties of your row objects have a capital first letter. JavaScript is case sensitive so they must be exactly the same

Comment: I've modified the column definition but that didnt help , i even removed the columns definitions and tried to treat it as an html table but the result was worse ( blank page ) so i have reverse it back to the past condition with fixed capitalized letters https://pastebin.com/4mXr7vPK

Comment: looking at the data the columns in your table arn't matched by values in your data. i.e. there is no "Segment" column in your data which is why the rows are comming out blank. if you can sort that then your table should work

Comment: thanks a lot man it's working now but with 1 error ( btw i switched to a simpler file and it worked ) but only one of the columns didn't render at all , all blank  - i checked the capitalization and everything seems correct -- column Manufacturing Price ( is the one that didnt render ) https://pastebin.com/ZcRe1TfA

Comment: you are having issues with your manufacturing price column because there is a lower case "p" in the property in the column definition, it should be an uppercase "P"

Comment: No Probs, Happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted, the issue is that it is using ***th*** tags for the first cell of each row in the table instead of ***td*** tags. ***th*** tags should only be used in the ***thead*** not the ***tbody***

Answer (score 0):

Working with .to_json(orient = "records") is always the best for Tabulator

Try this:

1)  If there's no Id yet, just:

```
df.insert(0,'id',range(1,len(df)+1))
df= df.to_json(orient='records')

JsonResponse({'myDF':df})
```

2)  Once back in Javascript, when you try to load your data from Ajax response, you must use

```
 data: eval(json.myDF)
```

in order to Tabulator read it correctly